# entering ssh private key password wihtout GUI

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring, keepassx

When I have to enter the password to unlock my private key for a ssh session, a GUI window pops up to "unlock private key". I would like to use keepassxc autotype here, but unfortunately this window does not even allow me to open any other windows. So I have to copy my password first in keepassxc, then start the ssh session and copy it into the field, thats quite bah...

Can I somehow deactivate the GUI prompt and use entering the password on the terminal?

Iam using Xubuntu 18.04

Comment: Try to unset the DISPLAY environment variable before running ssh command. This should pretend that you are running in text mode and not in GUI, so ssh should ask for passphrase to unlock the key in the terminal and not in the separate GUI window.

Comment: mh `echo $DISPLAY` is `:0.0` and it doesnt change anything when I do `DISPLAY=''` before running ssh

Comment: does ```unset DISPLAY``` work?

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Check if variables SSH_AUTH_SOCK and SSH_AGENT_PID are also set - if yes, unset them as well. It worked for me after unsetting all three.